# Drupal 7 Programmatically Replace Field in Views

Tags: text, replace, drupal, view

I have a question regarding Drupal 7 and the Views API.

I'm writing a module that replaces specific text in views. Essentially what I'm trying to do is scan text in a view (or page for that matter). Let's say the view has [special button] will be replaced with

```
l(t('button'),'mypage',array('query',array('page'=>$node->nid)));
```

Or whatever. Please understand this is pseudo code.

I've took a look at `hook_view()`, `hook_node_view()` (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and neither of them seem to work for me.

I've also looked at http://drupal.org/node/1510828 but that didn't seem to help me out.

Comment: You might want to consider posting this at [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting 'rewrite the output of this field' on the field/s ?
Or alternatively [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) should be able to do what you want.